# How does a thermal propagator work?

Tags: condensed-matter, temperature, many-body, propagator, thermal-field-theory

I am looking at a propagator in the Hubbard model (in the strong coupling limit) and my timescale is $\beta$. I see that for longer (imaginary) times $\tau$, the particle can propagate further away.
However, it can't move infinitely far, as the time is limited by $\beta$. If I increase $\beta$ I would assume the particle can propagate further away.

Now, when I think about $\beta$ not as a time scale, but as inverse temperature, I struggle to understand what is going on. If $\beta \rightarrow 0$, and temperature goes to infinity the particle can't propagate at all and if $\beta \rightarrow \infty$ the particle can propagate far. But is this how temperature works? It is not very intuitive to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is much intuitive reasoning to it: thermal propagator is a trick to lake thermal averaging look like evolution operator, which enables the use of well developed field theory techniques. The main intuition here comes from interpreting $\beta$ as... temperature.

The intuition does develop with experience, e.g., if you do lots of diagrammatic expansions, you will eventually get an idea of which diagrams are more or less important and what phenomena they correspond to. But this is more of a mathematical than physical intuition.

Comment: Does that mean that my first paragraph is correct?

Comment: @B.Brekke What do you mean when you say that *the particle may propagate further away*? That at low temperatures you have longer correlation length?

Comment: Yes, by "further away" I mean a longer correlation length

Comment: So this is the interpretation: at lower temperatures (i.e. bigger $\beta$) the correlation length is longer. I suppose that you should eventually obtain a divergent correlation length near the phase transition, whereas at very high temperatures the sites of the Hubbard model are nearly independent on each other.